# How to add LinkedIn's Burrow to a Docker Compose?

Tags: docker, apache-kafka, docker-compose, devops

It appears LinkedIn doesn't have an official Burrow docker image on Docker Hub, but there are others who have forked it.

However, I can't find any examples of how to add any of them to a docker compose file that spins up ZK and Kafka something like this.

What am I missing?

Comment: Could you show what you have tried so far? AFAIK, Burrow only needs to know where the bootstrap servers exist, and if that is available to be configured by a file or an Environment variable, then what issues are you having creating a compose file for this?

Comment: I don't even know where to begin. "Burrow only needs to know where the bootstrap servers exist" - is that an environment variable? If so, what is is called? I guess the whole question could be summed up as: Is there any documentation, anywhere?

Comment: Burrow's documentation is on Github... And last time I checked, it used a config file located at `/etc/burrow`, and mentioned on  Github, it says *use a Docker volume mount* - https://github.com/linkedin/Burrow#using-docker .. So, again, I ask, what issues are you running into so far?

Comment: An alternative to try is [**Remora**](https://github.com/zalando-incubator/remora), which does have a Docker compose example for you https://github.com/zalando-incubator/remora/blob/master/basic-example/docker-compose.yml

Comment: Thanks for the tip abour Remora, but I need to get Burrow to work.
I saw the documentation you pointed to, but it just says "A Docker Compose is also available for quick and easy development.", but then it just links to the generic Docker docs - not to an actual docker-compose file, nor are there any instructions on how to do this.
Anyway, I'll try the /etc/burrow route. Thank you.

Comment: Umm. Maybe you missed this? https://github.com/linkedin/Burrow/blob/master/docker-compose.yml

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I was looking for! If you put it in answer form I can accept it :)

Answer (score 3):

> It appears LinkedIn doesn't have an official Burrow docker image on Docker Hub

No, and while @toddpalino is one of the maintainers of Burrow, and has it on his Docker Hub account [he states that providing a Docker image is not a core tenant of the project](https://github.com/linkedin/Burrow/issues/321#issuecomment-357445957)

In any case, there is a Docker Compose file in the Github repo, so you're welcome to clone the project and build an image yourself. I have [opened a PR](https://github.com/linkedin/Burrow/pull/473) to make the README more clear that it does exists.

Regarding the configuration, the TOML file is linked into `/etc/burrow` of the container, and you would need to edit that file locally, and use a Compose `volume` mount to connect to an externally available Kafka broker or container.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like they introduced an official prebuilt image in the meantime:

https://github.com/linkedin/Burrow/pkgs/container/Burrow%2Fburrow